# Asterisk block incoming call with certain Caller IDs

Tags: asterisk

So I know this is a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find a good answer to it. I have a DID which is getting hit fairly hard (or at least for me, about 1-3 calls per day) with telemarketers from non 1-8XX numbers. However there are only a handful of numbers that call day in and day out. So naturally I would just like to block them so my phone doesn't ring and I don't get billed for a call.

I'm looking to send a SIP/404 or some other non-answer response-- not send them to voicemail or another recording. I don't really care about logging or anything like that, I just would like to be able to add (or remove) a number fairly easily so I can cut down on unnecessary calls.

Everything I find seems to be either too complex or too simple (only one blocked number) and I can't find a good medium. Hopefully someone else will have better insight! I am using Asterisk 1.6. Thank you!

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624458/asterisk-anti-ex-girlfriend-dial-plan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done something similar and like the other submitter, I used a database.  Instead of using the built int DB functionality, I used [cmd MySQL](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+MYSQL).  This was so I could write a web page that interacts with the same DB AND my DBA could do cross DB selects between this "Directory" table and the MySQL CDR.

In my example, I setup a table with 4 fields. `id` (auto_increment int), `number` (the phone number), `name` (The name of user), `ban` (an int that defaults to 0).  The example does 2 things, 1- it looks up name from the DB and sets that as the caller id (Since our POTS line doesn't communicate that) 2- It looks up to see if `ban` is set to 1, and blocks the call.

```
exten => s,1,Answer
exten => s,n,NoOp("Caller ID IS: ${CALLERID(number)}")
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Connect connid HOST USER PASSWORD database)
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} SELECT name,ban FROM directory WHERE number='${CALLERID(number)}')
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Fetch fetchid ${resultid} name ban)
exten => s,n,NoOp("We found: ${name} ${ban}")
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Clear ${resultid})
exten => s,n,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid});
exten => s,n,Set(CALLERID(name)=${name})
exten => s,10,NoOp()
exten => s,n,GotoIf($["${ban}" = "1"]?wedontlikeyou,s,1)
exten => s,n,Goto(mainmenu,s,1)
```

After this you'd have your [mainmenu] and [wedontlikeyou].  The later is your ban, it could be a simple hangup, error message, what ever you want.  My preference is [Congestion()](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Congestion) since that tends to make people think the phone number is out of service.

Answer (score 4):

How are your programming skills? I'm not sure about all the details, but I guess from your question:

- You have a US incoming number delivered to you via SIP protocol
- This is a number you pay incoming call costs for (1-800 ?)
- You have a number of caller-id numbers you want to block
- This number is big enough (more than 10, I guess) to not write one or two lines of code in extensions.conf for each number

Have a look at the code in the link kaptk2 mentioned.

And then have a look at the DB() functions of asterisk: [Asterisk function DB()](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+db). You would do a lookup of each incoming caller-id as database key and you can maintain database keys from the asterisk commandline.

Short example of DB management:

```
greenblatt*CLI> database put blockcaller 18005551212 1
Updated database successfully
greenblatt*CLI> database get blockcaller 18005551212
Value: 1
```

You could access the value with something like:

```
exten => s,1,GotoIf($[${DB(blockcaller/${CALLERID(num)}))} = 1]?blocked:ok
```

The best way to 'kill' the call would be to use the Hangup() function. Or if you insist on a 404 code: send it to a non-existing extension.